# Unable to load collectionview inside UItableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Collectionview reload not working when reload from custom tablecell.

I have put a dropdown inside one collectionview cell.this dropdown also not working.

Here is the code:

```
class HotelAvailableRoomsTVCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    //MARK: Life cycle
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "AvailableRoomCVCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "AvailableRoomCVCell")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        // Initialization code
    }

    func initCellWithData(roomJSON:JSON,indexPath:IndexPath,isSingle:Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

   }
}
```

In viewController:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HotelAvailableRoomsTVCell", for: indexPath) as! HotelAvailableRoomsTVCell
     cell.delegate = self
     cell.initCellWithData(roomJSON: (json)!, indexPath: indexPath as IndexPath, isSingle: true)
    return cell;
}
```

Screen is:
I have used a tableview with dynamic number of cells as collectionview. this collection view contains a dropdown as shown in image
[image]

Comment: What you mean by `not working` ? It shows nothing, it crashes, it do not updates visually ??

Comment: After writing self.collectionView.reloadData(),  a dropdown which was on a collectionViewCell stops taking action.

Comment: Which kind of dropdown ? It is not clear, please add some screenshots/explanations of your xibs/storyboards/layouts...

Comment: What does the cell delegate method do? After reload do the tableview's cellForRow and collectionview's cellForItem get called?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do this & check

```
class HotelAvailableRoomsTVCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource
```

You can also do this, (already done by me and its working),

Pass the data by creating var in `HotelAvailableRoomsTVCell`.

```
var collectionData : [String : Any] = []
```

In `cellForRow`

```
cell.collectionData = data
```

Comment: i passed collection data using  cell.initCellWithData(roomJSON: (json)!, indexPath: indexPath as IndexPath, isSingle: true)

Comment: @BaibhavSingh First do the 1st point that I mentioned and check whther your code is working or not.